# change the range of years shown on a select box - symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4

In my field `created_at`, in both `newSuccess.php` and `editSuccess.php`, is a select box and it only shows years from 2006 to 2016. How can I change this to show older years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the "years" option of the sfWidgetFormDate which is part of sfWidgetFormDateTime

```
// e.g. this year till 1960
$years = range(round(date("Y")), 1960);

// get the DateWidget
$this->widgetSchema["created_at"]->getDateWidget()->setOption("years", $years);
```

If you only need the date component, I would suggest to overwrite the basic form

```
$this->widgetSchema["created_at"] = new sfWidgetFormDate(array("years" => $years));
```

See also

- http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormDate